Deployment of Microsoft Entra Domain Services failes with internal error via Pulumi
I would like to set up an Entra Domain Service with Pulumi. The configuration of the domain service includes the minimum necessary configurations such as domain_name, domain_service_name, resource_group_name as well as domain_security_settings and replica_sets. I followed the standard Pulumi instructions.
When deploying, I get the following error message:
Code="InternalError" Message="Error testing domain controller connectivity through PowerShell. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 20.xx.xx.xxx:5986

main.py:
domain_name = the name of the domain -> contonso.local or contonso.onmicrosoft.com
subnet_name_3 = the name of the subnet
subnet_ip_3 = the ip address range within the vnet

# Ressource Group
ds_resource_group = create_ds_resource_group('ResourceGroupName')

# Get ID from subnetname
ds_subnet_id = get_ds_subnet_id(virtual_network, subnet_name_3)

# Domain Services
ds_domain_services = create_ds_domain_service(domain_name, ds_resource_group.name, ds_subnet_id)


virtual_network is a variable which holds the complete virtual network (can't show this because of data protection reasons)
domainservice.py:
import pulumi_azure_native as azure_native
from pulumi import Input, Output

# Ressource Group
def create_ds_resource_group(resource_group_name: str) -> Output[azure_native.resources.ResourceGroup]:
    return azure_native.resources.ResourceGroup('resourceGroupDs', resource_group_name=resource_group_name)


# Get ID from subnetname
def get_ds_subnet_id(virtual_network: Input[azure_native.network.VirtualNetwork], subnet_name_3: str) -> Output[str]:
    subnet_id: Output[str] = virtual_network.subnets.apply(
        lambda subnets: next(subnet.id for subnet in subnets if subnet.name == subnet_name_3)
    )
    return subnet_id


# Azure Entra Domain Services
def create_ds_domain_service(
    domain_service_name: str,
    resource_group_name: Input[str],
    subnet_id: Input[str],
) -> Output[azure_native.aad.DomainService]:
    domain_service = azure_native.aad.DomainService(
        'domainServiceDs',
        domain_name=domain_service_name,
        domain_service_name=domain_service_name,
        domain_security_settings=azure_native.aad.DomainSecuritySettingsArgs(
            ntlm_v1=azure_native.aad.NtlmV1.ENABLED,
            sync_ntlm_passwords=azure_native.aad.SyncNtlmPasswords.ENABLED,
            tls_v1=azure_native.aad.TlsV1.DISABLED,
        ),
        resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
        replica_sets=[
            azure_native.aad.ReplicaSetArgs(
                location='germanywestcentral',
                subnet_id=subnet_id,
            )
        ],
    )
    return domain_service


Azure suggests removing the resource and redeploying it.
However, only the domain service resource is removed. All additional resources that were created (load balancer, public IP address and network interface) remain and must be deleted manually. This leads to further problems with the nic, as it is connected to a virtual machine that does not exist.
I have already tried to remove all resources. Be it manually (powershell) or automatically (Pulumi). However, the resource is not created correctly even after several attempts. I will make a manual attempt to deploy directly via azure tomorrow. But the goal is to deploy the Azure Domain Service via Pulumi for documentation purposes.

can you provide your complete code ?

@SirraSneha i have updated the part that is important for the deployment.

@SirraSneha, and OP, please keep in mind that we should not post the complete code, but only [mre]

@Vega i have replaced important code snippets and company-related data with placeholders before posting. I think the code should still be readable and informative as it is now.

It is obvious that the should never post data as is. But I am talking about a reproductible code, and not the WHOLE code. It is a part of your task before posting to identify the code part that is causing the error/bug. That's why, once again you should read [mre] page but also [ask]

@Vega Can you tell me what I could do better? As I understand it, I have implemented most of the points from both instructions. I have also created the code to be able to run a test (off the vnet). I have also described the problem and the error message.
In addition, I am in contact with the support of Pulumi and Azure. If you see potential for improvement in any of these points, please give me a concrete example of what I can improve.
